# Subpath of EFS Access Point on Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-efs

I need to create many lambdas that connect to the same EFS. Considering that files on EFS are arranged something like this:-

```
- /parentDir
    - /childDir1
    - /childDir2
    - /childDir3
    - ...
```

Each lambda needs access to only one childDir.
Example:- Lambda1 only needs access to `parentDir/childDir1`.
Lambda2 only needs access to `parentDir/childDir2` and so on..

The EFS access point has been created for path `/parentDir`.

All the lambdas are able to use this EFS access point to get access to their desired directories. However, these lambdas are also able to access all the `childDirs` which is undesirable.

Also, considering that there is a [limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html#limits-efs-resources-per-account-per-region) of 120 Access Points per EFS, creating a new EFS access point for every lambda also would not be a solution here.

I am aware something similar can be achieved for EKS+EFS using a single EFS Access Point by specifying the EFS Access Point ID in the Persistent Volume's CSI `volumeHandle` and specifying the `subPath` for Pod's `volumeMount`:-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
...
csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-086d5ec1ad95cd54a::fsap-0015a3496006e9657
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: efs-volume-1-apeg
      mountPath: /data
      subPath: childDir3
...
```

So, is there a way to mount an EFS access point to Lambda in a way that the Lambda can only access a particular subPath(Example:- /parentDir/childDir2) and not all the directories?

Comment: got anything on this?

Comment: Nothing till now